# setText only sets one editText

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

I have an activity with 2 edittexts.  I set them with strings from intent or from a database depending on the activity that opens the activity.  So when I fill the edittexts from my database everything works fine both of them show the text that was in the string but when I try to fill the edittexts from intent only one of them fills.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("button");
    noteId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("noteId")
    setContentView(R.layout.notebook);
    title = (EditText) findViewById(r.id.etTitle);
    body = (EditText) findViewById(r.id.etBody);
    if (button == 1) {
        name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        notebody = getIntent().getExtras().getString("body");
        Log.i(tag, "title = " + name + "\nbody = " + notebody);
        body.setText(notebody);
        title.setText(name);
    } else if (button == 2) {
        db.open();
        cursor = db.lookup(noteId);
        db.close();
        name = cursor.getString(1);
        notebody = cursor.getString(2);
        title.setText(name);
        body.setText(notebody);
    }
```

the log statement shows both strings with the correct text but it only fills which ever setText is on top.  so if I put title above body it fills title but not body.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Note Title" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="Note Body"
            android:gravity="top">
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Anyone with a clue as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated because I just don't get it.

Comment: Post the code where you assign `body` and `title` using `findViewById`...

Comment: i edited my post to include how I assign the body and title edittexts, but this wasn't a problem because it works correctly when I set their texts using strings looked up by a cursor.

Comment: Could you also post your XML layout declaration?

Comment: I added my xml layout and also the way I set the text from cursor which works correctly.

Comment: What does this line output: Log.i(tag, "title = " + name + "\nbody = " + notebody);

Comment: Looks to be written correctly, perhaps you are not initializing one of them properly? You do have EditText title, body; and EditText imported right?

Comment: after trying just about everything I could think of, it hit me to try local variables instead of global ones. so now instead of name and notebody being used for both the intent and cursor, I use different ones for the intent and cursor and it works.  I don't know why it works but it does.